# How to load data from database when select particular date in angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular

I got last 1 year of data from my database with date wise i need to display data when user select particular date. so how we can do this in angular 2 we may use to bind every day and month with ngModel them we can send post request to the database with that number but i am not sure. is this right process we can do or do we have any efficient methods to display data. i haven't any idea how to do this. can you please share any resources or ideas.Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you the basis.

1. Make the Angular2 tutorial: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/
2. And if you want more detailed info about making a Restful API: https://scotch.io/tutorials/angular-2-http-requests-with-observables

Once you started coding and are facing your first code related issues you can post your code explaining your issues in a detailed way and the SO community will be glad to help you! ;)

**Edit:**

- You can make the Heroes Tutorial also in Javascript if you don't want to try TypeScript (even though I would suggest TypeScript).
- I personally made this tutorial and is very, very helpful. Have the patience to make it till the end, you will be rewarded. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion just now i successfully implement and i got data also.